# Finish FlutterActivity from Flutter when integrating Flutter to native host app [Add2App]

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-appbar, flutter-platform-channel

When integrating Flutter to a host app ([docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen)) there is a few ways to do it, one of them (simplest) is open Flutter in a new Activity via `FlutterActivity` class.
Like this:

```
// Java
hostActivity.startActivity(                
  FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine("my_engine_id").build(context)
);
```

Traditionally for Android style windows on Flutter side we create AppBar with *Back* button.

This AppBar *back* button and Android system *back* button must behave the same: foreground activity must been closed (finish) when pressing to *back* button.

Currently system *back* button really closes the `FlutterActivity`, 
but how to emulate this behaviour from flutters AppBar *back* button?

```
// Dart - Flutter side
...
child: AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
          // WHAT MUST BE HERE?
      }),
...
```

PS Platform channel between Flutter side and host established - I can call any code from any side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found:

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

> Removes the topmost Flutter instance, presenting what was before it.
>
> On Android, removes this activity from the stack and returns to the
>   previous activity.

Documentation here: [api reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html)

Comment: Another option that came to mind, but I have not tried to implement it:
Extend your _activity_ from `FlutterActivity` and implement some kind of receiving signal to finish yourself. Via platform channels call method to send signal to finish, and your runned activity will finish yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: () => {
            if (Navigator.canPop(context))
              {Navigator.pop(context)}
            else
              {SystemNavigator.pop()}
          },
        )
...
```

Comment: Clean and easy method.